# How can I change the `DivideByZeroException` from throwing into handling?

Tags: c#

I want to give `int` a similar behavior like `float`, i.e. to make it able to divide by 0 *but* I want it to return 0.
Furthermore, I want to overload `/` operator for `int` to return a float (which I know how to do but only mentioned for completeness).
I don't want to check if the denominator is 0 on each and every division; I'd also rather not even wait for the exception to be thrown, as exceptions are slow altogether.
ideally I want to edit the very throwing of the exception as closer to the "root" as possible (lowest level of the system (CLR?) detecting an `int` division by zero). Is there any code that I can edit like in `System` or anywhere else?
EDIT:
The whole idea is to (ideally) use a fixed precision float. Since current implementations of such a type are computationally expensive and some incomplete, using an int seemed the better idea, with the caveats of handling infinite result of divisions.
Hence the need to intercept EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO and somehow handle it to be ignored and return an "odd" value in the int range.

Comment: this sounds like you really want to just use float instead of int.

Comment: `... to make it able to divide by 0 but I want it to return 0.` <= nothing can be divided by 0, its not a c# thing its a math thing.

Comment: So you want to change the base rules of the language (and of mathematics)?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: I need a fixed precision type.

Comment: Dividing a float by zero will give infinity, so what you are proposing isn't really *like float*.

Comment: @UnholySheep @Igor: this is another discussion that I barely help myself not to start ;) suffice to say in my "universe" 0 is not a number but a limit, so any integer, so infinity. I'm considering other aproaches like adding an infinity by using `nullable`. Come on, the question is not about mathematics. It's about coding.

Comment: I would focus more on your design, rather than solving this problem, because even if you 'hack' it somehow, this isn't really a good practice. Imagine if it was a huge project with many things depending on this logic. This isn't a way to go. Take one step back, rethink it. Do you really need this? Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: I've just read that some PowerPC architecture and some RTOS division by zero yields... guess what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you can't do that. You can't redefine math. About the best solution you could get is to have an extension method. Something like:

```
public static int SafeDivision(this int nom, int denom)
{
    return denom != 0 ? nom/denom : 0;
}
```

Which you could use like:

```
Console.WriteLine(10.SafeDivision(0));    // prints 0
Console.WriteLine(10.SafeDivision(2));    // prints 5
```

Which is a bit fiddly to use...

Or as @MikeNakis suggested in his answer, you can create your own struct with your own logic.

Comment: It's too of a nuisance. This is yet another case where overloading operator extensions would have come in handy. An almost not bad result of 21 ms with no 0 check and 24 ms with 0 check (1000000 times).

Comment: I think that's the way to go. Don't try to overload the "standard" integer division, since it's very likely other part of your program will rely to the "standard" way of doing it. Using a `SafeDivision` as suggested means that you will use such behaviour only when you want to use it.

Comment: @GianPaolo: +1'd for the solid argument. Indeed this answer is the most "direct" and efficient solution for my question so far.

Comment: I chose this answer as it's the best compromise. But guys, `you can't redefine math` is not a valid argument. At least for `float` and `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with `int`.

And there is no code in `System` or anywhere else that you can edit to achieve anything of that sort.

However, what you *can* do is define your own `struct Integer` which will encapsulate an `int`, and then define overloaded operators for it which will handle all the arithmetic in all the ways you want.  You can even have it play an mp3 with Leonard Cohen's *Hallelujah* every time it detects and prevents a division by zero.

You will *have to* check if the denominator is zero on each and every division.  That will save you the overhead of throwing an exception, which will probably be of the order of tens of thousands of times more expensive.

Comment: Boxing is resource expensive for me. It's definitely not mathematics who decides at runtime that division by zero isn't possible. Like @Matt Burland said: division by 0 yields infinity (with floats). So which part exactly, from the CPU to compiler, impedes ints to divide by zero at the same time allowing floats?

Comment: It is the CPU.  Specifically, the Arithmetic and Logic Unit (ALU) of the CPU.

Comment: And a `struct` does not necessarily imply boxing, certainly not any more than an `int` does.  As far as the generated machine code is concerned, a `struct` containing nothing but an `int` is equivalent to an `int`, and if by any chance it turns out that it is not exactly equivalent, then that would be a shortcoming of the compiler / jitter, and only a matter of time until it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - I tried it and merely encapsulating an `int` in a `Int` struct yielded 40 ms for one normal division (1000000 times) versus 16 ms for a direct `int` division (1000000 times).

Comment: @mireazma: float division by zero is defined in the IEEE-754 standard

Comment: To my understanding, as per [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141002-00/?p=43933) it's the Windows NT kernel that decides raising EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO or EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW based on further conditional code. I voted up the answer but can't accept it just yet.

Comment: @mireazma well, at the moment I cannot back up my claim, because it has been a long time since I last dealt with these things, but from my days of x86 programming I remember that interrupt vector 0 was "Divide Error", meaning that if the CPU encountered a division by zero it would trigger an interrupt 0.  Of course, it would then be up to the operating system and the language runtime to translate this into an exception, but you can think of the interrupt as being the starting cause of the exception.  I cannot verify that things still work like this today.